How to create new custom page in civicrm?
I need to create a new custom page in civicrm for whatsapp integration. I need a page to show the whatsapp template listing. How to do this in civicrm?

Would suggest to use CiviCRM message template functionality instead building your own one.

Is there a method to integrate WhatsApp with Civicrm by manually creating pages through hard coding?

You can use SMS inbuild functionality of Civi
